# PtrSafe in Excel 2003 is giving me problems

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently making some VBA code applicable for the new win7 machines on the job. This means that many function has to be added with the new 64-bit compatibility. I am currently following the guidelines from [this](http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/apideclarations.asp) homepage. I find them very useful and implemented following:

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Declare PtrSafe Function CreateProcess Lib "kernel32"  'More code, see below.
#Else
    Declare Function CreateProcess Lib "kernel32" 'More code, see below.
#EndIf
```

however, currently VBA is giving me following error message when I save my code:

[image: this error code]

NOTE: The code above contains the code described in the previous mentioned link: [from jkp-ads](http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/apideclarations.asp). The error appears in the `Declare PtrSafe Function CreateProcess Lib "kernel32" Alias "CreateProcessA"`. The full code can be found [here](http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/apideclarations.asp).

What am I missing here?
Thanks!

**Update**
My full code:

```
Option Explicit
Const INFINITE = &HFFFF
Const STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW = &H1
Private Enum enSW
    SW_HIDE = 0
    SW_NORMAL = 1
    SW_MAXIMIZE = 3
    SW_MINIMIZE = 6
End Enum

Private Type PROCESS_INFORMATION
    hProcess As Long
    hThread As Long
    dwProcessId As Long
    dwThreadId As Long
End Type

Private Type STARTUPINFO
    cb As Long
    lpReserved As String
    lpDesktop As String
    lpTitle As String
    dwX As Long
    dwY As Long
    dwXSize As Long
    dwYSize As Long
    dwXCountChars As Long
    dwYCountChars As Long
    dwFillAttribute As Long
    dwFlags As Long
    wShowWindow As Integer
    cbReserved2 As Integer
    lpReserved2 As Byte
    hStdInput As Long
    hStdOutput As Long
    hStdError As Long
End Type

Private Type SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    nLength As Long
    lpSecurityDescriptor As Long
    bInheritHandle As Long
End Type

Private Enum enPriority_Class
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = &H20
    IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS = &H40
    HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS = &H80
End Enum
#If VBA7 Then
private Declare PtrSafe Function CreateProcess Lib "kernel32" _
Alias "CreateProcessA" (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, _
                        ByVal lpCommandLine As String, _
                        lpProcessAttributes As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, _
                        lpThreadAttributes As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, _
                        ByVal bInheritHandles As Long, _
                        ByVal dwCreationFlags As Long, _
                        lpEnvironment As Any, _
                        ByVal lpCurrentDriectory As String, _
                        lpStartupInfo As STARTUPINFO, _
                        lpProcessInformation As PROCESS_INFORMATION) As LongPtr

#Else
Declare Function CreateProcess Lib "kernel32" _
Alias "CreateProcessA" (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, _
                       ByVal lpCommandLine As String, _
                       lpProcessAttributes As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, _
                       lpThreadAttributes As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, _
                        ByVal bInheritHandles As Long, _
                        ByVal dwCreationFlags As Long, _
                        lpEnvironment As Any, _
                        ByVal lpCurrentDriectory As String, _
                        lpStartupInfo As STARTUPINFO, _
                        lpProcessInformation As PROCESS_INFORMATION) As Long
#End If
```

Now, I want to emphasize a few things. First, I am running Excel 2003 and Windows XP 32bit. In addition to this **I have not attempted to run the code yet**. Why you may ask. The reason is simple. The editor comes up with a compile error before I am able to do anything. This Compile error can be seen in the picture above this piece of code. I have taken a screenshot of some of the code and especially where the compile error occurs. This is how it looks:

[image: Error]

**UpdateUpdate:** Just found [this article from MS support.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983043) It appears that the resolution is following: *"To resolve this issue, ignore the "Compile error" and run the VBA code in the 64-bit version of the Office 2010 program."* I still hope some solution exist though.

Comment: Looks Ok to me. except there has to be a space in `#EndIf` which I guess is a typo. BTW did you see [THIS](http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/apideclarations.asp) link?

Comment: @PradeepKumar: That's the exact same link given by the OP in the question :-)  Also, the VBA editor will add the space automatically, so that shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: Ah! yes :) I missed that...

Comment: What line is highlighted when you get this error?  I don't see anything wrong with the code you show... though I can't speak to the `.. some more code` bit which you don't show.

Comment: Wait a minute... your second `Declare` statement says `Liv` instead of `Lib`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: Liv is a typo here on this site not in my code, sorry about that. 
The error appears (red highlighted text) in the Declare PtrSafe Function CreateProcess Lib "kernel32".

Comment: Have you declared all attributes correctly? For example `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES`, `STARTUPINFO`, `PROCESS_INFORMATION` ?

Answer (score 2):

Further to my comment below your question (which you have ignored... by mistake I guess?) I believe you are getting that error because you have not specified all the parameters correctly.

Try this and it will compile just fine.

```
Const INFINITE = &HFFFF
Const STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW = &H1
Private Enum enSW
    SW_HIDE = 0
    SW_NORMAL = 1
    SW_MAXIMIZE = 3
    SW_MINIMIZE = 6
End Enum

Private Type PROCESS_INFORMATION
    hProcess As Long
    hThread As Long
    dwProcessId As Long
    dwThreadId As Long
End Type

Private Type STARTUPINFO
    cb As Long
    lpReserved As String
    lpDesktop As String
    lpTitle As String
    dwX As Long
    dwY As Long
    dwXSize As Long
    dwYSize As Long
    dwXCountChars As Long
    dwYCountChars As Long
    dwFillAttribute As Long
    dwFlags As Long
    wShowWindow As Integer
    cbReserved2 As Integer
    lpReserved2 As Byte
    hStdInput As Long
    hStdOutput As Long
    hStdError As Long
End Type

Private Type SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    nLength As Long
    lpSecurityDescriptor As Long
    bInheritHandle As Long
End Type

Private Enum enPriority_Class
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = &H20
    IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS = &H40
    HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS = &H80
End Enum

#If VBA7 Then
    Declare PtrSafe Function CreateProcess Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "CreateProcessA" (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, _
                            ByVal lpCommandLine As String, _
                            lpProcessAttributes As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, _
                            lpThreadAttributes As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, _
                            ByVal bInheritHandles As Long, _
                            ByVal dwCreationFlags As Long, _
                            lpEnvironment As Any, _
                            ByVal lpCurrentDriectory As String, _
                            lpStartupInfo As STARTUPINFO, _
                            lpProcessInformation As PROCESS_INFORMATION) As LongPtr
#Else
    Declare Function CreateProcess Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "CreateProcessA" (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, _
                            ByVal lpCommandLine As String, _
                            lpProcessAttributes As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, _
                            lpThreadAttributes As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, _
                            ByVal bInheritHandles As Long, _
                            ByVal dwCreationFlags As Long, _
                            lpEnvironment As Any, _
                            ByVal lpCurrentDriectory As String, _
                            lpStartupInfo As STARTUPINFO, _
                            lpProcessInformation As PROCESS_INFORMATION) As Long
#End If
```

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for your comments! I just tried copy pasting the code above into my module, but the compile error still occours and the entire function (`PrtSafe CreateProcess`) appears in red. 
I am running Excel 2003 and windows XP 32 bit.

Comment: Can you update your question with the exact code? Or a screenshot?

Comment: @SteewDK: Just saw your screenshot. Delete the word `Private` before `Declare` and see what happens?

Comment: @SteewDK: It it still doesn't work then try this. Replace `#If VBA7` with `#IF Win64`

Comment: unfortunately neither the removal of `Private` nor replacement of `VBA7` with `Win64` seems to remove the compile error. 
This code is in a module, yes, and in addition I am calling these functions from the same module. I appreciate your help!

Comment: I found this interesting link [MS support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983043). What's interesting is the resolution: "To resolve this issue, ignore the "Compile error" and run the VBA code in the 64-bit version of the Office 2010 program."

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution, but a path of investigation.

It looks like the compiler is looking at the stuff under `#If VBA7 Then`. But this shouldn't be happening at all in Excel 2003.

Try replacing whatever is under `#If VBA7 Then` with garbage, and add one declaration in the `#Else` part, e.g.

```
#If VBA7 Then
    ksjdhfg lkjsdh fgkjh,dlgf sldjkgflsd g 'obvious syntax error
#Else
    Const vOlder As String = "older VBA"
    Declare Function CreateProcess Lib "kernel32" '... keep this part as it was
#End If
```

Then try to run this to see if it compiles:

```
Sub tester()
    Debug.Print vOlder
End Sub
```

This should compile and run fine in Excel 2003 since it has an older version of VBA than 7.0. The stuff below `#If VBA7 Then` should get completely ignored (regardless of any syntax errors or anything else) and the stuff under `#Else`, e.g. `vOlder`, should be accessible.

Let us know if this helps you trace the error.

Comment: Actually a really good point! I tried this and it works. 
However, the compile error still appears when the other piece of code is put in. What I noticed was that once the compile error (see the error message from before) appears the PtrSafe is highlighted in black - the rest of the code `Declare PtrSafe Function CreateProcess Lib "kernel32" Alias "CreateProcessA"` is in red. It seams like it expects something from PtrSafe in some way.

Comment: `It looks like the compiler is looking at the stuff under #If VBA7 Then. But this shouldn't be happening at all in Excel 2003.` No that is not true :) A compiler checks each and every line. And I mean when you click on `Debug | Compile VBA Project`

Comment: @SteewDK: You seem to have missed my comment under your question?

Comment: @SiddharthRout well, the compile error did not occour if i remove the `Declare PtrSafe Function CreateProcess Lib "kernel32" Alias "CreateProcessA"` piece of code but instead just type `blalbalbvals `

Comment: @SteewDK: I will come to this in a moment. Can you first reply to my comment?

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Ok, I guess you could say the compiler "looks" at the line of garbage I wrote; but clearly, it doesn't put it in its mouth!

Comment: Do you mean to say that with `ksjdhfg lkjsdh fgkjh,dlgf sldjkgflsd g`, Sub tester() is able to run without giving any error in Excel 2003? I can't check as I don't have Excel 2003 but yes, it gives an error in Excel 2010.

Comment: I just tested it in Excel 2010 and it works just fine for me!! Of course, you have to move the gibberish to the `#Else` part, because the `#If VBA7` part *does* get compiled in Excel 2010 (and the opposite in Excel 2003).